# Are symlinks in sync with the parent file all the time?

Tags: symlink, rsyslog

I have a log file which is having a ownership for only root. This file consists of active incoming logs & is continuously updated any time.  I need to create a symlink for this file and change the ownership to syslog. I am not sure if symlinked file is always in sync in with the parent file , and if changing the owner works as i need rsyslog to pick the file and send it to a remote nxlog server.

Comment: Which user is your `rsyslog` running as?  Does it drop privileges after starting up to a different user?  Can you not change the read permissions on the log for the group to some group that the `rsyslog` user is a member of?

Comment: How can i add rsyslog to lets say 'root' ?

Comment: I suggest you pick one of the answers below for this question (which was about symlinks), and create a new question describing your specific rsyslog issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A symbolic link is just a reference to the actual file. There is no synchronization or something like that.

If you look at the `ls` output for a symbuolic link you generally see something like:

```
ls -l /bin/bzcmp 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 jul  9  2014 /bin/bzcmp -> bzdiff
```

As you can see the file `/bin/bzcmp` is just 6 bytes in size which happens to be `bzdiff`. You can also use `readlink` to see where a symbolic link points to.

For a link it is unnecessary (and impossible) to change the permissions because the target permissions will be in effect. Therefore it is also unnecessary to change the owner of the link (because of lrwxrwx**rwx**).

Answer (score 2):

Symlinks aren't copies of files, they're essentially pointers which point at the same file.  That means for example, that you can't do anything about permissions, if you can't access the original file then no matter what you do with the symlink, you can't get around that.

Also, they are always 'in sync' because they always point directly to the same file.

Answer (score 0):

The symbolic link is just a pointer to a file / folder, like a shortcut.
It will always have lrwxrwxrwx permissions. As pointed in another answer, the target permissions will be in effect.

In contrary with this, a hard link is directory entry (a file) pointing to the same inode. Even if you change the name of the other file, a hardlink still points to the file. This is true even if you delete the original file. The file will be erased when all files pointing to that inode are erased. 
Changing the permissions of the original file or hard-linked file will change the permissions of all files pointing to the same inode - so in this case the permissions are synchronized.